# Keycloak connection with tls enabled database

Tags: keycloak, keycloak-services, keycloak-rest-api, keycloak-connect

I have been trying to connect the keycloak to a custom database that is ssl/tls enabled. The problem I am facing is when I add the custom configuration to add my database which is ssl/tls enabled, the keycloak container is failing and giving me - Path does not chain with any of the trust anchors. I am using latest version of keycloak "quay.io/keycloak/keycloak:20.0.3"
I am new to keycloak so any help or pointers will be appreciated!!

I am new to keycloak. I am trying to connect ssl enabled mysql database as a custom database to the keycloak. I am trying to getting it configured using kubernetes

Comment: Could you copy the exact error message?